# is rendering thousands of Canvas elements performant in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I need to render a graph in a datagrid. I was thinking of rendering one canvas element in each row's first column/cell and then render a dot and a line there. Now the thing is that there will be thousands of rows in the datagrid. Before i begin implementing this i would prefer insight from anybody who already has experience on this. Is this aproach going to perform slowly? Am I choosing the best path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't show all the data at once to the user, you could leverage data virtualization concepts.
This [PDF](http://bea.stollnitz.com/files/52/DataVirtualization.pdf) helped me understand key concepts of data virtualization.

That said, using a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is not a good idea. The bigger the amount of data, the lower level component you should use. In your case, that would be [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).
I believe a quick look at both their definition is worth all the explanations.

I once saw a blogger on msdn who showed an example where he would load over a million of drawings and it would not lag one bit. It is totally possible, but I can't find that link anymore.

HTH,

Bab.